# Помогите найти ошибку в JSP / JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Есть jsp-файл конфигурации

```
<%@ page import="ru.javawebinar.basejava.model.ContactType" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Список всех резюме</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="fragments/header.jsp"/>
<section>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>Имя</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${resumes}" var="resume">
            <jsp:useBean id="resume" type="ru.javawebinar.basejava.model.Resume"/>
            <tr>
                <td><a href="resume?uuid=${resume.uuid}&action=view">${resume.fullName}</a></td>
                <td><%=resume.getContact(ContactType.EMAIL)%></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
    </table>
</section>
<jsp:include page="fragments/footer.jsp"/>
</body>
</html>
```

И связанный с ним сервлет

```
public class ResumeServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private SqlStorage sqlStorage;

    @Override
    public void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.apache.jsp");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sqlStorage = new SqlStorage(Config.get().getDbUrl(),
                Config.get().getDbUser(),
                Config.get().getDbPassword());
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws javax.servlet.ServletException, IOException {
        request.setAttribute("resumes", sqlStorage.getSortedStorage());
        request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/jsp/list.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Tomcat выдает следующие ошибки:

```
HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Type Exception Report

Message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:197)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    ru.javawebinar.basejava.web.ResumeServlet.doGet(ResumeServlet.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
Root Cause

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.list_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:128)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:59)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:192)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:413)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    ru.javawebinar.basejava.web.ResumeServlet.doGet(ResumeServlet.java:34)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: В таких случаях лучше еще указывать зависимости (например, содержимое pom.xml)

Comment: Попробуйте положить jstl.jar в tomact/lib папку